# What is the proper way to test for null values in a trigger?

Tags: mysql

I have a trigger set to fire on update. I'm working on an older version of mysql before it supported raising errors hence my call to a non-existent "raise_error" function that ends the trigger. I'm trying to prevent a field from being updated if a field is not null. My trigger looks like this:

```
IF (new.Value <> old.Value AND old.Value IS NOT NULL) THEN
        CALL raise_error;
END IF;
```

This does not work since the following completes successfully:

```
UPDATE Table SET Value = NULL WHERE Value IS NOT NULL
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Why not just disallow NULL values for the column by table definition?

Comment: Because I'm using the fact that it's null to discover if it is a fresh item ready for updating.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql's [null-safe comparison operator `<=>`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to), which considers two nulls to be "equal":

```
IF (new.Value <=> old.Value AND old.Value IS NOT NULL) THEN
    CALL raise_error;
END IF;
```

Comment: What you suggest doesn't address the logic I'm looking for, but a modified version might, however, this does not work!

(new.Value <=> old.Value AND (old.Value IS NOT NULL OR new.Value <=> NULL)).

If new.Value = NULL and old.Value != NULL, this doesn't return true for some reason.

I'm using new.Value <> old.Value to initiate the test only if this particular field is being changed. I have several other fields that have similar tests.

Comment: @Shadouts `new.Value <> old.Value` is never true if at least one of the values is null. You must use `<=>` is there can be nulls.

Comment: Okay but I'm trying to discover not equal to. <=> is equal to.

Comment: @Shadouts then use `NOT A <=> B`

Comment: Some more experimentation leads me to believe my problem might have a different nature.I tried some other comparisons including the one above but now I'm getting my trigger to fire even when I'm not touching the Value field (undesireable). Mysql seems to be passing Value as NULL on an update statement that doesn't include changes to Value. Using `NOT old.Value <=> new.Value` fires the trigger even if the update doesn't include change to Value.